# How to call an AsyncTaskLoader in constant intervall

Tags: android

Following Situation:

I fetch data from an REST API using an implementation of an AsyncTaskLoader. I want to update the data in constant intervalls. My approach is first to start the loader in the Activity(`getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, MainActivity.this).forceLoad();`), instantiate a TimerTask , pass the activity (the one the timerTask is instantiated at) and load the data with `getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, MainActivity.this).forceLoad();` within `run()` in my TimerTask class.

Problem: From the activitie's reference, I don't call  `getSupportLoaderManager()`, only `activityContext.getLoaderManager()`

When trying to do it with `activityContext.getLoaderManager()`, I don't know what is correct for the third parameter.

Is the whole approach wrong? If so, what is a good way to load the data in constant intervalls?

Comment: Type `activityContext.getLoaderManager()` and press the DOT button in your keyboard then hit `CTRL + SPACE` and you will get the right hint. Note: I am assuming you are using Android Studio.

Comment: That autoHint menue(or however it's called) should help me how?

Comment: `I don't know what is correct for the third parameter.` It will suggest `initLoader(int key, Bundle bundle, LoaderCallbacks callback)` and other else. `I can't know what is correct for the third parameter.` The 3rd parameter is `LoaderCallbacks` which is an interface.

Comment: If this code `getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, MainActivity.this)` is valid then I can safely assume that your activity implements the LoaderCallbacks e.g. `class MainActivity implements LoaderCallbacks` . And if you are calling it within fragment then you must implement the LoaderCallbacks in your Fragment as well.